# Hooking mouse events, including WM_SETCURSOR, to prevent a certain cursor type appearing

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, mouse

In some circumstances when I call **DoModal** on one of my *ATL::CDialogImpl<...> dialogs*, I get the wait cursor flashing up for a few milliseconds.  It's very annoying and not very aesthetically pleasing, not to mention after days of experimentation I've failed to identify the cause given my dialog initialisation is very fast.

So I was wondering if there's a way to hook into the message queue and identify when the cursor is changed to **IDC_WAIT** (it's not changed to that anywhere in my software, or anywhere in WTL as far as I can see), then simply have that message ignored.  As an experiment I did the following:

```
DWORD thread_id, pid;

thread_id = ::GetWindowThreadProcessId(m_hWnd, &pid);

hook = SetWindowsHookExW(WH_GETMESSAGE, GetMsgProc, nullptr, thread_id);
```

and then my GetMsgProc as follows:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    auto m = reinterpret_cast<MSG*>(lParam);

    if (m->message == WM_SETCURSOR)
    {
        // Change cursor
        
        ::SetCursor(Global_Cursors.Get().Cursor(Resource_Cursors::Arrow));
        
        // Ignore the message.

        m->message = WM_NULL;
    }
    
    return CallNextHookEx(hook, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Interestingly I never get a **WM_SETCURSOR** message, though I do get lots of others.  What mistake have I made here?

Comment: Try using `WH_CALLWNDPROC` instead of `WH_GETMESSAGE`. Not all window messages are posted to a thread's message queue

Comment: I'm hitting my breakpoint with a CWPRETSTRUCT and WH_CALLWNDPROC but not getting any WM_SETCURSOR.

Comment: NVM about that last comment, it should be a CWPSTRUCT, and I'm getting them now.   m->message = WM_NULL has no effect however.

Comment: A `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook cannot modify or block messages, as stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644975(v=vs.85)): "*The CallWndProc hook procedure can examine the message, but it cannot modify it. After the hook procedure returns control to the system, the message is passed to the window procedure.*"

Comment: Whereas a `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook can modify messages, as stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644981(v=vs.85)): "*The GetMsgProc hook procedure can examine or modify the message. After the hook procedure returns control to the system, the GetMessage or PeekMessage function returns the message, along with any modifications, to the application that originally called it.*"

Comment: So back to the question.  You're saying it's not possible to intercept and prevent a wait cursor from showing.

Comment: Since `WH_CALLWNDPROC` can't modify or block messages, you will probably have to [subclass the window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview) that is receiving the message, and then simply discard the message instead of passing it to the default procedure. Otherwise, the only other option I can think of is to [detour](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/) the `SetCursor()` function itself to have it ignore any cursors you don't want.

Comment: Yes, "detour" is a no-no.  The other software devs will think I've gone mad.  There's something weird going on, i.e. I think the IDC_WAIT cursor is being set by ::DialogBoxParam, which is called somewhere in WTL, and I don't know why.  There must be a simple explanation but I can't find what it could possibly be.

Comment: [*WM_SETCURSOR*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/setting-the-cursor-image) message is sent to a window if the mouse causes the cursor to move within a window. There is no document about the message and the logic which Windows uses to change the cursor. By the way, It's unnecessary that Windows uses `SetCursor` to set the cursor.

Comment: I'm not setting the wait cursor anywhere, and neither is WTL or ATL as far as I can see.  I hooked events and managed to get a call stack with breakpoint on IDC_WAIT in the hook, and it seemed to be caused by DialogBoxParam.  It's not coming from me at all.

Comment: As [*WM_SETCURSOR*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-setcursor) said, the message is sent to a window if the mouse causes the cursor to move within a window and mouse input is not captured. You may use [spy++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2022) to find out the correct message.